# partitioning mariadb for large table error

Tags: database, partitioning, database-administration

We have problem that a table is growing fast an has now 270M records,
we dont need data older than a week so we want to delete them on a twee INNODB galera cluster on Mariadb server latest version.

We have figured out partitioning is the best solution (maybe there are other solutions please let me know)

The following problem we have with partitioning:

I'm trying to make partioning work with the following table.

```
id  int(11)  (Primary)
user  int(11)  (index)
device  int(10) unsigned (index)  
datetime  bigint(20) (index)  (javascript timestamp)
created_at  datetime NULL (index)  
prev_block  int(11)  (index)
difficulty  double   
hash  binary(32) (unique)
```

Our main goal is to have partioning by week.
We have tried using:

- partition by hash( datetime  DIV (60*60*24)) partitions 7;
- partition by hash(DAY(created_at))  partitions 31;

Either i get a

Error in query (1486): Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function 
are not allowed

Or a

Error in query (1503): A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

What would be the 'best' way to partition this table?

Comment: Why not delete the unnecessary data?

Comment: On Innodb table, it locks rows we have found that on our table with large set of data and increasing fast it create deadlocks and table will hang and stop all the services.